# PHP ERROR : mysqli_stmt_bind_param() Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php

i am facing a problem in my php file, the error is comming from the parameters in the third statement, but i can not find where is it. Here is my PHP file:

```
$client = "test";
$resto = "test";

$st1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT client_id FROM Clients WHERE email = '$client'");
$res1 = mysqli_fetch_array($st1);
$clientID = $res1["client_id"];

echo "CLIENT ID = ";
echo $clientID;

$st2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT restaurant_id FROM Restaurants WHERE email = '$resto'");
$res2 = mysqli_fetch_array($st2);
$restaurantID = $res2["restaurant_id"];

echo "RESTO ID = ";
echo $restaurantID;

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO reservations (resto_id, client_id) VALUES ($restaurantID,$clientID)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ii",$restaurantID,$clientID);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: A: you're not using placeholders. RT\*F. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Thank you for your unswer, can you precise more about what should i do to solve the problem?

Comment: `$restaurantID,$clientID` should be placeholders, not variables, then bind them. Also use parameterized queries everywhere, not just in `insert`.

Comment: ...as in `(?,?)`. as in "the manual",

Comment: You mean to change    $restaurantID,$clientID    to '.$restaurantID.','.$clientID.' ?

Comment: actually, I was first :p and you're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your statement like bellow

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO reservations (resto_id, client_id) VALUES ( ? , ? )");
```

Comment: Thank you for your unswer, it works !

Comment: @LieHili you should mark it as the correct  answer then 

Comment: I'm new on StackOverFlow, is it done now?

Comment: Yes, thank you and cheers